# Checkbox for load and hide stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to create checkbox for load and hide CSS stylesheet file.

I make checkbox and I don`t attach stylesheet to the page.

Now when I check the checkbox not happend to the page

My JS

```
<script>// RTL 
    $('#show_rtl').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('head').append('<link media="all" type="text/css" href="../css/rtl.css" id="thr_rtl_css_custom" rel="stylesheet">')
        } else {
            $('#thr_rtl_css_custom').remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML checkbox input:

```
<label>
    <input class="sw-title" type="checkbox" id="show_rtl"> Right to left (RTL)
</label>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you not to do this because you will make a request everytime you select the checkbox.

What you can do instead is to add the rules based on an class that will toggle in the parent element. In this way, you can add the "right-to-left" css rules in the default stylesheet.

```js
    $('#checkMe').click(function(){
       $('#mainElement').toggleClass('show_rtl');
    });
```

```css
    .show_rtl p{
        direction: rtl;
    }
    .blueOrRed{
        background: blue;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
    }
    .show_rtl .blueOrRed{
        background: red;
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainElement">

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkMe" value="toggle Class">
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <div class="blueOrRed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer

I need to load and attach stylesheet based on address like 

http://..../rtl.css

I dont need to load class

Comment: Ok, this should work; Just make sure you add the correct path to your css file :
`var stylesheet = $('<link>').attr({
        "rel" : "stylesheet",
        "type" : "text/css",
        "href" : "../rtl.css"
    });

    $('#checkMe').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) $('head').append(stylesheet);
        else $('head').find(stylesheet).remove();
    });
`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to attach a onchange handler before the document is fully loaded. So the DOM-Element/Checkbox you are trying to attach it to does not exist at this point of time.

Rewrite your script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show_rtl').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('head').append('<link media="all" type="text/css" href="../css/rtl.css" id="thr_rtl_css_custom" rel="stylesheet">')
        }else{
            $('#thr_rtl_css_custom').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

The `$(document).ready()` function makes sure that the function it's passed isn't executed until the page is finished loading. It can also be written shorthand like this: `$(function() { <your code here> });`

Comment: Thanks for answer . can you explain more . i do but not worked

Comment: Check your developer tools (usually F12) in your browser. You should find a request which tries to load your .css-file and make sure it does not fail. In case it fails it will also print a warning to your console (error404) which would be an indicator for a wrong filepath.
The script postet here definetly works with your, in the question given extract.

Comment: newBee No idon`t have any error about css not find ....
Can you show me your js in jsfiddle ? thanks